# Is it possible to form a PDA for this language?

Tags: automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

$$L=\left \{ a^nb^m|n\leq m\leq 2n \right \}$$
Is this even context free?
I am asking because by looking at the condition, for an expression that holds:$n< m<2n$ can be written as : $a^nb^nb^c (c<n)$.
Following this term(taken from geeks for geeks https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-the-language-is-context-free-or-not/) :"An expression that involves counting and comparison of three or more variables independently is not context free language, as stack allows comparison of only two variables at a time."
So here I need to make sure that number of first b's is the same as a's and the second b's are less than n$(c<n)$, which makes me think that L might not be context free(although it specified clearly to build PDA for this).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the language is context-free.  I recommend that you ignore that article on geeks for geeks; its so-called "analysis" is stated in a way that is highly ambiguous, and appears to be faulty in some cases.

Hint: The language has the form $L = \{a^j a^k b^k b^{2j}\}$.  Build a PDA that non-deterministically guesses $j$.  (I assume you know how to build a PDA for $\{a^n b^n\}$ and $\{a^n b^{2n}\}$.)